# Number of Automorphisms of a given Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a small graph, how can you manually calculate the number of automorphisms? I thought of seeing the number of nodes of a particular degree and permuting among them, but aren't there other factors to consider, like the node being part of a cycle, etc? For example, this graph:

[image]

Suppose *b* had two more edges going to two different nodes, then you can't map *b* to *g*, even though they have the same degree. So how do you do this?

Comment: A long time ago I wrote some code in SML to calculate graph automorphisms. If you like I can try to find it and send it to you.

Comment: Isn't this an NP problem? Of what I know, there is a polynomial solution only if the vertex degrees are limited.

Comment: It is NP, but not known to be NP-complete. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190532/what-is-the-significance-of-the-graph-isomorphism-problem/190675#190675

Comment: Ah ... thanks for the link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is in general not even simple to check if two graphs are isomorphic. 
In your case, we see that $a,b,m$ are the only degree 1 nodes, hence any automorphism must permute them. Next $c$ is characterized by being the only node with degree 1 neighbours, hence $c$ must be a fixed point (which at the same instant shows that $a,b,m$ may be permuted arbitrarily).
You may then note that $d$ can be mapped to any of $d,e,f,g$, but then $e$ must be mapped to the common neighbour of $\phi(d)$ and $\phi(c)=c$. 
Finally you can map $f$ to any of the remaining neighbours of $c$ and the rest, i.e. the images of $g, h, k$ are then determined.
We conclude that the automorphism gorup is isomorphic to $S_3\times D_4$.