# Graph with many automorphisms

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, automorphism-group

Let $G(V,E)$ be an undirected graph, potentially with loops and multi-edges. Assume the following two properties hold:

1. $\forall a \in V, \exists f \in \operatorname{Aut}(G), f(a) \ne a$
2. $\forall f\in \operatorname{Aut}(G), \exists a \in V, f(a) = a $

Prove: $10 \le |V| $

Comment: I know a small brute-force solution, but want to find more eligible

Comment: Do you know an example of a graph having those two properties?

Comment: It seems to be a NP problem not easy to solve and brute force might be the only option: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213716/number-of-automorphisms-of-a-given-graph